# How to remove duplicate values from dynamic select in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

trying to figure this out with no such luck. Basically we populating a select with values from the service that it's being retrieved from. But there are duplicates in the select. Here's the code that's doing it. I'd like to remove the duplicates from what's getting returned that are in the "theProduct.name". I know this question has been asked before but I can't figure this out. The image attached is the select where it's happening. Thanks

```
 function populateSearchProducts(data) {

    var theData = data.data.results;
     $field.empty().append('<option value="">&nbsp;</option>');

    for (var p in theData) {
      var theProduct = theData[p];
      $field.append('<option value="'+theProduct.id+'">'+theProduct.name+'</option>');
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can remove the duplicates before you call the function `populateSearchProducts()`. Basically `data` should be free of duplicates before you pass it in.

Comment: Do those duplicated products have the same id?

Comment: @diogenesgg they don't - just the same "name"

Comment: Inside your for loop, add another variable, call it oldVar. Assign your old product to it. Compare your new product with the old one using an if statement. Then inside your if statement, it should add the product if it will not match the old product.

Comment: @erics15 so if they have different `id` what are you supposed to use as the value when you output the `option` element?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio, thanks we're getting the "name" even if the ID is the same.

Comment: Sorry, what? I was asking what you would put as the value of the `option` element if let's say there are 2 array elements with the same name with an `id` of `123` and `678` respectively. If you're only displaying one `option`, is the `id` going to be `123` or `678`?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio it'll just be whatever ID comes first and then get rid of the next one in sequence (so just one name for each respective ID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a filter to remove duplicates from the input data:

```
function populateSearchProducts(data) {

    var theData = data.data.results.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
        return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });

    $field.empty().append('<option value="">&nbsp;</option>');

    for (var p in theData) {
      var theProduct = theData[p];
      $field.append('<option value="'+theProduct.id+'">'+theProduct.name+'</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i think the issue is that once you go into "theProduct.name", that's when you need to deduplicate. Tried the above and the same thing is happening

Comment: This is kinda a general solution to remove duplicates from an array in JavaScript. Not sure how your input data is.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function populateSearchProducts(data) {
     data = data.data.results;

     const dupes = new Set();

     for(const {name, id} of Object.values(data)){
          if(dupes.has(name)) continue;
          $field.append(`<option value='${id}' > ${name} </option>`);              
          dupes.add(name);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the items already added to the DOM and then use a filter before adding new elements.

In the code below, the filter is looking at the `id` of each element to filter them out.  If you want, you could use `name` (or any other attribute) to detect the duplicates and filter them out.

Something along the lines of:

```js
var dataArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'one'},
  {id: 2, name: 'two'},
  {id: 3, name: 'three'},
  {id: 4, name: 'four'},
  {id: 2, name: 'two'}, // dupe
  {id: 5, name: 'five'},
  {id: 3, name: 'three'} // dupe
]

function populateSearchProducts(data, $field) {
    //var theData = data.data.results;
    var theData = data;
    
    $field.empty().append('<option value="">&nbsp;</option>');
    // to keep track of the ones already in the drop-down
    var alreadyAdded = [];
    
    for (let p of theData) {
      if(alreadyAdded.filter( item => item.id === p.id ).length <= 0 ){
            $field.append('<option value="'+p.id+'">'+p.name+'</option>');
            alreadyAdded.push(p);
      }      
    }    
 }
 
 // when docuemnt ready, populate the field
 $(function(){
    var field = $("#selOptions");
    populateSearchProducts(dataArray, field);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selOptions" />
```

*updated based on comments*

Comment: OP mentioned that the `id` of the duplicates are different.

Comment: I saw that afterwards... I think we need more clarifications on what to filter one but the concept still applies... thanks @uom-pgregorio

Comment: OP responded by saying just use the first one you encounter. Your solution should still work.